SAS Title Suppression within ODS HTML Output Preceding Proc Reports
An easy yet stubborn title issue that doesn't seem to have a clear answer across various sites: I have many proc report statements (only 2 shown below), preceded by an overall document title and description text.
Currently, the overall title and ods text appear in the output, but the first of the two proc reports (salesit) is now missing its title in the output.
What is the proper way to code an overall document title for an ODS output to ensure the overall title does not suppress the succeeding titles that follow or repeat itself for each table. (None of the common suggestions have worked, such as: clearing the document title, adding 'nogtitle', changing the placement of the succeeding titles, numbering consecutively, etc.). [Question updated/shortened for clarity.]
ods listing close;
ods html body = 'filepath\missingsurveys.html';

title 'Missing Surveys Over Time';
ods text = 'The tables below display missing surveys by customer id';

proc report data = salesit;
column n customer_id sale_date;
compute n;
_n+1;
n=_n;
endcomp;
title 'Customer_Ids from IT Sales';
endcomp;
run;

proc report data = salespmo;
column n customer_id sale_date;
compute n;
_n+1;
n=_n;
endcomp;
title 'Customer_Ids from Management Support Sales';
endcomp;
run;

ods html close;
ods listing; 



In SAS, the TITLE statement is a global statement.  Even if you put it 'inside' a PROC REPORT step, it's not really part of that step.  The TITLE statement will always execute, even if there is no data for the PROC REPORT step, or even if the PROC REPORT step errors.  Every time the TITLE statement executes, it will replace the existing title(s).  If you want to execute the TITLE statement conditionally, you could add some macro language logic which would conditionally execute the TITLE statement.

I'm not really understanding your question, but as a best practice, since the TITLE statement is a global statement, it's clearer to place it outside of a PROC STEP.  Also it's a good idea to clear the title after it no longer applies.  For example:
ods listing close;
ods html body = 'filepath\missingsurveys.html';

title 'Missing Surveys Over Time'; *I am confused by this title, what is it for? ;
ods text = 'The tables below display missing surveys by customer id';

title1 'Customer_Ids from IT Sales';
proc report data = salesit;
  column n customer_id sale_date;
  compute n;
    _n+1;
    n=_n;
  endcomp;
run;
title1; *clear title;

title1 'Customer_Ids from Management Support Sales';    
proc report data = salespmo;
  column n customer_id sale_date;
  compute n;
    _n+1;
    n=_n;
  endcomp;
run;
title1; *clear title;

ods html close;
ods listing; 

Every time you issue a TITLE statement it will clear all the existing title(s).  If you want to have a main title that is maintained, with sub-titles added, you can use TITLE1 for a main title, and TITLE2 for a subtitle.  When TITLE2 executes it will clear TITLE2-TITLE10, but will not clear TITLE1.
